# RandomPoint returns compiler errors on RegionIntersection of two Meshs?

Tags: bugs, random, compile, mesh

Consider the `intersection` of two [ConvexHullMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html)'s, `m1` and `m2`.

```
m1 = ConvexHullMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}];
m2 = ConvexHullMesh@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}];
intersection = RegionIntersection[m1, m2];
```

All have a non-zero [Volume](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Volume.html)

```
Volume /@ {m1, m2, intersection}
```

And one can obtain [RandomPoint](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html)s on m1 and m2

```
RandomPoint@m1  (*works*)
RandomPoint@m2 (*works*)
```

in contrast,

```
RandomPoint@intersection (*returns CompiledFunction errors*)
```

[image: CompiledFunction: Argument Region <code>Mesh</code>CrossingCount errors]

All run on 11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)

**Update 1**:  The 2D version of the above works fine without errors.

**Update 2**: (23 May 2019) Wolfram Tech Support confirms that this is a bug and is investigating.

Comment: Thanks for informing support about this!

Comment: `RandomPoint[TriangulateMesh[intersection]]` seems to work around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error, but I don't know what went wrong. This is probably worth a bug report at Wolfram Support.

I found out that `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` can help to circumvent the problems.

```
M = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@intersection;
RandomPoint@M
```

Comment: Your `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` workaround does the job in v11.3.0